# NSURLSession requests to SSL server + MITM attacks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, security, ssl, https

I'm in the process of improving the security between requests made from an OS X app, using NSURLSession, and an apache server in the backend.

It seems the majority of (free) providers only seem to allow certificate generation for domain names, rather than IPs. If I setup SSL with a valid certificate on a domain name, can requests on the client-side to this domain name be intercepted and rerouted, e.g. using the hosts file, to fool my app?

Normal workflow example:

1. App makes request to https://example.com using NSURLSession
2. example.com sends encrypted response.
3. App uses that response as normal.

Workflow when manipulated by malicious user:

1. User changes hosts file on local machine to point example.com to
   local IP.
2. Local IP has valid SSL certificate, although not
   necessarily the same one.
3. App makes request to https://example.com
   using NSURLSession.
4. App doesn't know that the example.com request
   was manipulated and sent to a local server, and handles response as
   normal.

Are my concerns valid? Can a request to an SSL server be manipulated like that to fool my app? Are there APIs to catch anything like that, ensuring manipulated requests would fail, so only my true server is trusted by the app?

Experiences, suggestions, and input here are appreciated.

Comment: You can pin the certificate, essentially that is verifyig the certificate you receive is the one you expect.

Comment: Got any examples you can point me to? @zaph